# how to filter and show fields of content types in custom page tpl.php file

Tags: theming, nodes

I have the following fields in content type ‘Articles’

Year:
Volume:
Issue: 
Title:
Description:
Upload file:

Now I want to create a custom pages tpl.php and categorized based on Year, Volume, Issue. So the output should be like below. 
On clicking issues, it should display the all the posts.  (2013/volume 3/Issue 1)

2013
Volume3 – Issue1, Issue 2

2012
Volume 2 – Issue1, Issue 2, Issue 3

2011
Volume 1 – Issue1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of modifying any template files, you should most probably be looking into the [Views](https://drupal.org/project/views) module, a module that, per its project page, is useful for a variety of tasks, one of which seems particularly on point here:

> You want a monthly archive similar to the typical Movable Type/Wordpress archives that displays a link to the in the form of "Month, YYYY (X)" where X is the number of posts that month, and displays them in a block. The links lead to a simple list of posts for that month.

Answer (score 0):

I could be misreading your question, but it sounds like what you want is a view. To do this you will need the [Views Module](https://drupal.org/project/views). Once it is installed (**Modules > Install New Module**), you will create a new view (go to **Structure > Views > Add New View**); you can choose to display it as a page, a block, or both. Then, choose to return fields, pick the fields you want from your Article content type, and apply the proper sorting and grouping to get what you need.

If you want to use a `tpl.php` file to change the markup of your view results, check out this page on [views template files](https://api.drupal.org/api/views/theme!theme.inc/group/views_templates/7).

Hope that helps!